# Smart Vertical flow layout

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout

I'm looking for the following behaviour in a JPanel Layout (Swing): basically it would arrange the components in a Vertical way, one bellow each other.

When the components can't fit vertically in the container, it should add the next one in a new row. This would continue dynamically, adding new rows as needed.

It would look likes this, after adding 3 labels:

```
+--------------------------+
|  label1                  |
|  label2                  |
|  label3                  |
+--------------------------+
```

After adding: 2 more labels:

```
+--------------------------+
|  label1  label4          |
|  label2  label5          |
|  label3                  |
+--------------------------+
```

Finally, after adding 2 more labels it would look like this:

```
+--------------------------+
|  label1  label4  label7  |
|  label2  label5          |
|  label3  label6          |
+--------------------------+
```

Is this behaviour possible to achieve with one of the current layouts?

Should I create one myself?

How would you solve this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Here's a code snippet which illustrates the usage:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fill, flowY, wrap 4));
panel.add(new JLabel("row 1, column 1"));
panel.add(new JLabel("row 2, column 1"));
panel.add(new JLabel("row 3, column 1"));
panel.add(new JLabel("row 1, column 2")); // etc.
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I was hopping the Layout would manage the column automatically, so when it doesn' fit in one column, it would add the component to the next column.

Comment: Also, I checked your code and the class LC does not have a method wrap that takes a parameter:
http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/javadoc/net/miginfocom/layout/LC.html#wrap()

Comment: It's the case here. Fourth label "row 1, column 2" is going to be added in the second column while first three will be in the first.

Comment: Fixed, Layout Constraint creator LC doesn't support all constraint builders, i.e. wrap(int). You can use String version like the one here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution found. Thanks to Boris, using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/):

```
LC lc_Y = (new LC()).fill().flowY();
lc_Y.setWrapAfter(ITEMS_PER_COLUMN);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(lc_Y));
```

Now, it would be perfect if there was no need to specify the amount of items per column. I mean, the Layout would try to fill vertically the container with as many items in the same row as possible.